# Output is high before the expected clock edge in the sequence detector

Tags: verilog, sequence, system-verilog, test-bench

I wrote Verilog code for a "1011" sequence detector. But, in simulation, output is high when it receives "101".  For example, it is high one clock cycle before the actual clock edge. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
module main(
input clk,
input rst,
input x,
output y
);
reg temp;
reg [1:0] present_state;
reg [1:0] next_state;
parameter [1:0] state_0 = 2'b00;
parameter [1:0] state_1 = 2'b01;
parameter [1:0] state_2 = 2'b10;
parameter [1:0] state_3 = 2'b11;


always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
if(rst)
present_state <= state_0;
else
present_state <= next_state;
end

always @(x or present_state)
begin
case(present_state)
state_0 : if( x )
begin
next_state  = state_1;
temp    = 1'b0;
end
else
begin
next_state  = state_0;
temp   = 1'b0;
end
state_1 : if( x )
begin
next_state  = state_1;
temp    = 1'b0;
end
else
begin
next_state  = state_2;
temp    = 1'b0;
end
state_2 : if( x )
begin
next_state  = state_3;
temp    = 1'b0;
end
else
begin
next_state  = state_0;  
temp    = 1'b0;   
end                                                   
state_3 : if( x )
begin
next_state  = state_1;
temp    = 1'b1;
end
else 
begin
next_state  = state_2;
temp   = 1'b0;
end
default  :     begin
next_state  = state_0;
temp    = 1'b0; 
end
                             
endcase
end 
assign y = temp;
endmodule
//test bench
module tb_main(

);
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg x;
wire y;

main uut( clk,
rst,
x,
y
);
initial 
begin
clk = 1'b0;
rst = 1'b1;
x =1'b0;
#150 rst = 1'b0;
end

always
#50 clk <= ~clk;

initial
begin
 
#150 x = 1'b0;
#100 x = 1'b1;
#100 x = 1'b0;
#100 x = 1'b1;
#200 x = 1'b0;
#100 x = 1'b1;
#200 rst = 1'b1;
#200 $stop;
end
endmodule
```

My simulation results are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The test bench data should be derived by the clock, as is the case with synchronous design, so at least update the test bench to:

```
initial
begin
  #150; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b0;
  #100; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b1;
  #100; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b0;
  #100; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b1;
  #200; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b0;
  #100; @(posedge clk) x = 1'b1;
  #200; @(posedge clk) rst = 1'b1;
  #200; @(posedge clk) $stop;
end
```

Hopefully that will help you to move along, but there may be other issues for you to find ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the testbench code.  You have a simulation race condition.

You need to drive the synchronous input (`x`) from the testbench in the same way it is sampled in the design:

- `@(posedge clk)`
- Nonblocking assignments: `<=`

Here is testbench code that fixes the problem:

```
module tb_main;
   reg clk;
   reg rst;
   reg x;
   wire y;

main uut (
    clk,
    rst,
    x,
    y
);

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    rst = 1;
    x = 0;
    #150 rst = 0;
end

always #50 clk <= ~clk;

initial begin
    repeat (3) @(posedge clk); x <= 1;
    repeat (1) @(posedge clk); x <= 0;
    repeat (1) @(posedge clk); x <= 1;
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk); x <= 0;
    repeat (1) @(posedge clk); x <= 1;
    #200 rst = 1;
    #200 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Waveforms showing the correct output timing:

[image: waves]